# hhvm + nginx + wordpress - upload issue

Tags: nginx, wordpress, hhvm

I installed nginx 1.7.12 + hhvm 3.7.0 + wordpress 4.2.2 on digital ocean droplet.

I am trying to upload a theme that is  17 mb. While uploading, after exactly 30 seconds the upload restarts itself 3-4 times and than I get an error page.

All the settings are default, I even tryed to put this in php.ini (hhvm):

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

But nothing changed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the client informs it that it's going to send a body larger than the `client_max_body_size` nginx will send a 413 response and closing the connection.
Change your config by adding the `client_max_body_size 50m` or any number bigger to allow larger uploads.
From the docs:

```
Syntax:     client_max_body_size size;
Default:    client_max_body_size 1m;
Context:    http, server, location
```

[Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Answer (score 0):

- You should try to restart nginx after the update of the php.ini
- You should also make sure that you have modified the php.ini of the web service a not the one for the CLI of php.

Comment: I fixed it by putting this in nginx.conf

client_max_body_size 200M;

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to a number of things. From the NGINX configuration *(which typically results in an http error)* to wrong user/group permissions which can result in a variety of errors.

The main thing you should check for, is a correct configuration of www-data user and group permissions. Which is related to the NGINX configuration.

After that, you'll want to look at the configurations of:

- NGINX virtual host
- NGINX server block
- HHVM php.ini
- HHVM server.ini

The solution lies somewhere inside the above. If you can provide some more information it will be easier to help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: I fixed it by putting this in nginx.conf

client_max_body_size 200M;